# how to find code-functions that called before c++ main

Tags: c++

how to find code-functions that is called before c++ main? I am trying to locate which functions are called in order to initialize static variables by functions and thus executed before main.

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: You may want to use a debugger and set a data breakpoint over the static variables of your interest.

Comment: on linux:g++, on windows: microsoft visual studio

Comment: @Matteo Italia: in fact I am trying to find-locate static variables which are initialized that way

Comment: @A.Papadopoulos I updated my answer with what I believe it would be good to find static/global variables. If you have the same source code (cross-platform code) you can use linux scripting utilities to invoke nm/objdump to do the things you need. I really think this is a nice endeavor.

Answer (score 3):

In GCCs case you have:

```
__CTOR_LIST__ (list of initialization functions called - pointers) 
__DTOR_LIST__ (list of functions called for cleanup)
```

They are automatically generated by the compiler for each translation unit (C/C++ file).

You can find more information about this [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html). For other compilers this must be similar but you can "guess" it by using utilities like [objdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) or [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) (for your compiler suite, of course).

We called those pointer functions ( void (*func)(void) ) manually on a custom embedded platform on which we used g++.

---

I saw that you are interested in finding the static/global variables.

For this task you can really use some tools like objdump and nm (previously mentioned). First create 2-3 test files (and compile them to obtain the .o/.obj) and see how the static/global variables are seen by those tools (in the .obj/.o files. Once you see that, you can go through all the .obj/.o files with a script and make a list of the static/global variables.

Comment: I have already tried this, but I am not able to find which of them (
thousands variables) are initialized by function call

Comment: @A.Papadopoulos Isn't there a difference between uninitialized variables and initialized variables in a .o file?

Comment: @A.Papadopoulos See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159666/where-is-global-variable-in-elf-file There is indeed a difference between initialized and uninitialized variables. This should help you tweak your script to see variables that are (or not) assigned a value when being globally/statically defined.

Comment: @A.Papadopoulos You should do some tests for your particular case in an .o file and see if there are differences with objdump/nm.

Comment: global-static variables initialized by function call and global-static variables with no initialization are symbols in the uninitialized data section (known as BSS) and listed by nm as "B" (global scope) or "b" (file scope)

Comment: @A.Papadopoulos then you can do a dual scan - both in file and in .obj files but this would involve parsing each cpp file and correlate that with information from the .obj

Answer (score 2):

This is extremely compiler and/or platform specific.  In fact, I just spent the better part of a day chasing down an incompatibility between two different compilers' way of handling this.

Try your compiler's documentation, in particular the sections on C++ runtime initialization.

Answer (score 2):

The best way at run-time is to find the startup file for your C++ run-time.  This is the code that executes before main.  It is responsible for system initialization including initializing memory, static variables, and calling constructors of global objects.  In MS VC++ this file is crt0.c.  You can find it by setting a breakpoint at main and then looking at the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past, and now do from day 1 of a C++ project, is to remove all global variables. The only way at that point is to create everything with initialization functions that you can call from `main()` (of course, you can break down initialization processes by creating many distinct initialization functions, it is actually highly recommended.)

If you're stuck with a project where you can't change the code that deeply, then you've got to tweak things manually here and there such as the order in which files get linked, which is a really weak method to guarantee proper initialization (although I used that technique a while back when I wrote my own linker, I could actually look for a number in the initialization function to have them ordered by that number.)

One solution, is to use a Coverage tool. This will show all the functions that get called. In case of C++, that means you'll see all the constructors that get called and thus find the corresponding global variables. Obviously, class A uses class B, B may not have any globals... it's still a lot of work. In this case, you want to return immediately once you reach `main()`:

```
int main()
{
     return;
     ...your other code...
}
```

This is temporary until you get the list you're looking for. The tools to run coverage in the GNU C++ suite are named `gcov`. If you search on such you'll easily find many examples.

Again, as Joe Z mentioned, problems with globals initialized before `main()` are going to be a moving target depending on your environment (compiler, libraries, versions, etc.) so not having such initialization in the first place is best. There are still cases where it is required, though: for example, when I use the singleton pattern, you must initialize a global variable to null at least. (Also singletons can cause problems in a potentially multi-threaded environment...)