# Include static symbols in GNU ld map file?

Tags: c, dictionary, static, linker, ld

It's good programming practice to define module-local symbols as static (assuming C). Unfortunately, that interferes with analysis of the resulting object/binary files. For example, GNU ld map file (-Map=...) doesn't include static symbols, so important information is missed (like, how many symbols there're really in a module, size of each function defined, etc.).

Is there way to ask GNU ld to include static symbols in a map file, without modifying original source code? (It's obvious that one can make static modifier conditional, but that's quite a chore when analyzing bunch of 3rd-party projects.)

Comment: Soon after posting this question, I also submitted a GNU ld feature request, which stays uncared for since then: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16566

Answer (score 3):

Although the linker map file and `nm` don't include symbols without extern linkage, `objdump` does (as long as debug information is available).  You'll want the `-t` option.

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17159666/103167)